# Displaying search results using textbox_changing on listview from JSON data

Tags: c#, json, listview, uwp

I have a textbox to do a search using textbox_textchanging and a listview. When the user typed the letter `o`, it will show the search result of the letter `o` on listview and when user typed the word `omapukis`, it will show the search result from The word `omapukis`.

XAML:

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="searchBox" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Margin="10,0,10,10" 
    Text="" 
    Foreground="Black" 
    Background="#E6FDFDFD" 
    BorderBrush="#FF7A7A7A" 
    PlaceholderText="Search in Indonesia Products &amp; Bussiness"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" 
    FontSize="16" 
    TextChanging="searchBox_TextChanging" />
<ListView 
    x:Name="suggestionList" 
    Grid.RowSpan="2" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Margin="67,75,0,0" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="1135" Height="400" 
    Background="White" 
    BorderBrush="Black" 
    BorderThickness="1"
    Visibility="Collapsed"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
    ItemClick="suggestionList_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" >
                    <TextBlock 
                        x:Name="Nama" 
                        Text="{Binding Title}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" 
                        TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                        Visibility="Visible" 
                        Foreground="Black"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Margin="10,0,10,10"
                        SelectionHighlightColor="#FFBFA342"
                        FontSize="16"/>
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="{Binding ID}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" 
                        TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        Foreground="#FFAAAAAA"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<SearchClass> suggestionDatasourceDetail = new ObservableCollection<SearchClass>();
ObservableCollection<SearchClass> historyDatasourceDetail = new ObservableCollection<SearchClass>();
private async void searchBox_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    string keyword = searchBox.Text;
    suggestionList.ItemsSource = null;
    suggestionList.Items.Clear();
    suggestionDatasourceDetail.Clear();
    koneksiErrorStack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    requestErrorStack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    if (connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
    {
        itemGridView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        busyIndicator.IsActive = true;

        try
        {
            string urlPath = "http://.../suggest.json?q=" + keyword + "&module=listings&page=1&token=3f63-dc43-c8d5-eb45-8cbf-b72d-9d98-800f";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

            var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>{};

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlPath);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
                RequestException();
            }

            string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
            JsonArray jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();

            foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData)
            {
                JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();

                double id = groupObject2["id"].GetNumber();
                string title = groupObject2["title"].GetString();
                string type = groupObject2.ContainsKey("type") && groupObject2["type"] != null ? groupObject2["type"].GetString() : string.Empty;

                SearchClass file1 = new SearchClass();
                file1.ID = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                file1.Title = title;

                if (type != string.Empty)
                {
                    file1.Type = type;
                }
                if (file1.Type != "blog")
                {
                    suggestionDatasourceDetail.Add(file1);
                }
            }
            suggestionList.ItemsSource = searchDatasourceDetail;

            if (suggestionDatasourceDetail.Count == 0)
            {
                busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
                loading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                suggestionList.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            else
            {
                busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
                loading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                suggestionList.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
            loading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            RequestException();
            suggestionList.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
        loading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ConnectionException();
        suggestionList.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

I have a problem, when typing the letter `o`, it will show the search result of the letter `o` on listview, while when user type `omapukis`, then Will display the search results will show from `o`, `om`, `oma`, `oma`, `omapukis`. I want to display search results from the word `omapukis` only (search results with the last letter or word only).
And after that I search for the word `kalingga`, then the search results will appear from `om`, `oma`, `oma`, `omapukis`, `ka`, `kali`, `kalingga`. I want to display search results from the word `kalingga` only (search results with the last letter or word only).

How to resolve it in order to display search results in listview of only the last letter or word entered by the user?

Comment: Are you using UWP ? or WPF ?

Comment: @saurabh I am using UWP

Answer (score 1):

You should be using AutoSuggestBox : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox and use TaskCancellation for previous search. Basically have a logic to cancel the previous search in case user has modified anything on the AutoSuggestBox. Something like this..

```
private CancellationTokenSource CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

public async Task StartSearch(string query)
    {
        this.CTS.Cancel(true);
        this.CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (this.CTS.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Your actual searching logic... If you decide to update the UI here then make sure this runs on UI Thread.

                    if (this.CTS.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   // Logger...
                }
            }, this.CTS.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException taskCnclErr)
        {
            // You can ignore this error
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Logger...
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Now, hook the StartSearch() method to the event trigger from AutoSuggestBox 
TextChanged or QuerySubmitted

Comment: Or you can do the same thing by TextChange event also on a TextBox, in case you don't want to use a new control

Comment: I encountered an error like this picture:https://1drv.ms/i/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7lldbkPaS4eC2n9W
The code I use is https://1drv.ms/f/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7luJvP6IDCOgklW3

Comment: The error seems to be of doing a UI operation on non UI thread. Try removing Task.Run

Comment: saurabh: If I delete Tak.Run, then it can not display search results of letters or words typed by the user. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for a little while before searching your data. Try adding this snippet at the beginnig of the `TextChanging` method (add `_lockable` as private field of type `object`):

```
lock (_lockable)
{
    var term = searchBox.Text;

    await Task.Delay(250);

    if (term != searchBox.Text)
        return;
}
```

This will wait a quarter of a second after the user entered the text before starting the search. If the term changed, it would only search the new term. Try experimenting with the delay time to find the optimal time for your scenario.

Comment: I encountered an error like this picture:https://1drv.ms/f/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7l1Kp4cIYK2hh3OL

Comment: @Rose - You have to initialize the field. In the ctor, add `_lockable = new object;`

Comment: I've declared _locakble to private object _lockable; But an error message appears like the one given in the previous comment